# Arrange Rows in a MySQL table using a "sort" column

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, cycle

I arrange photos on an album by using a column "sort" in the table.
This means that an album will be displayed with "ORDER BY sort".

I have a feature that allows users to arrange the photos on an album, by dragging and dropping photos, in javascript, and then pressing the "Save" button.

An array (with the sorted Photo IDs) is sent to the process (in PHP), and then I want to re-sort the rows on the table.

The easiest way in my mind to do is:

```
for ($c=0; $c<$length; $c++) {
    mysql_query('UPDATE photos SET sort="'.$c.'" WHERE id="'.$array[$c].'"');
}
```

(please ignore sanitization, duplicates and other verifications here)

But I'm worried about the amount of queries that are made in a cycle like this.

How would you improve this approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  You could try merging it in one big update and sanitizing your input so you wouldn't be vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @Zombaya Thanks. As I said in the question, please ignore sanitization and other verifications. However, how would I merge it in one big update? That's what I wanted, btw. The problem is in the "WHERE" clause.

Comment: I'm mistaken, you can't do that.  You can do it with insert-statements, I switched those.  I did find a [blog](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/05/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-one-single-query.html) which maybe can help you along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't think there's anything wrong with issuing multiple queries. Did you test it? Are you sure it would be a performance bottleneck? I don't think so.

But anyway, **solution #1** is to use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) in conjunction with the `VALUES` clause. In that case, though, you need to explicitly specify data for all columns of the table, otherwise the data in those columns will be erased (set to default value).

**Solution #2** is just for fun. I don't think anyone would use it, but still:

```
UPDATE photos
SET sort = (
  SELECT sort FROM (
    SELECT 1 id, 1 sort UNION
    SELECT 2 id, 2 sort UNION
    SELECT 123 id, 3 sort) t
  WHERE t.id = photos.id)
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 123)
```

**Solution #3** is virtually the same as Zombaya's:

```
UPDATE photos
SET sort =
  IF(id = 1, 1,
  IF(id = 2, 2,
  IF(id = 123, 3,
    0)))
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 123)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [blog](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/05/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-one-single-query.html) in my comment had this as a solution

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `field_name` = CASE `id`
     WHEN '1' THEN 'value_1'
     WHEN '2' THEN 'value_2'
     WHEN '3' THEN 'value_3'
     ELSE `field_name`
END
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a WHERE on `id`, otherwise it will go through every row in the table and try to update it.

Answer (score 1):

If you used prepared statements, you could prepare the statement once and then run it several times, once for each photo. This is more efficient than doing that many `mysql_query`s, because the parsing and query planning is done only once.